# how to detect from where a tab is getting activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website in which the main menu is composed of horizontal and vertical tabs.
Out of these I have first horizontal and vertical tab active at page reload.Also when i change the horizontal tabs the vertical tab contents also change. Now i want to detect certain parameters in url and if present then redirect to tabs that are not active on page load. I have tried the following

- removing by default active of initial tabs from index
- adding (if parameters present) the class "active"
- adding class active at the end of every javascript

I tried debugging the four javascripts that get loaded with the page but somehow after everything gets loaded the by default tabs get activated and none else.
The only thing that worked and which is obviously not a feasible solution was i added class active at the end of logger.js that to after an interval of 3 seconds.

what might be happening? has anybody experienced this?

Comment: seeing your code would be helpful, but it sounds like your first tab is hard-coded with the "active" class.  If so, remove that from the html, then test each tab to see if it matches your condition.

Comment: Please put your code here, else create a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net might be helpful.

Comment: @ryan i did remove the hard coded active tabs. But somehow right at the end it gets added again

Answer (score 0):

You did everything in correct way. You just want to implement condition to the active tab. Means if there is an aactive tab is present then no need to execute default active tab. If there is no any active then and only then execute the default active tab